# How can I transfer values from one Website to another website (Spring Boot - Angular) ?

Tags: java, angular, spring, rest, spring-boot

I have a problem with a case :How can I transfer values to another website?

Website A : The user has a unique ID (customer ID). With a Button i will transfer the customer id to another Website.

Website B: This website needs the values (custumer id) from the first website to display the data.

How to do this ? How can i transfer the value from webseit A to webseite B

information -> 
Website A : Jsf
Website B : Spring Boot and Angular

Thanks lot .

Comment: The normal way is to create rest service in Website B then call them from Website A and send your data.

Comment: I can think of JMS messages, sent from one system to the other, if no sychronous state must to be enforced.

Comment: Local storage is private as discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12437836/html5-web-storage-can-different-websites-overwrite-each-other-s-data-on-a-user So to "pass" information, store it on the server and have both web sites access it from the server.

Comment: @DeborahK How can i use the LocalStorage for 2 Webpages ? I think they use all ther specific space

Comment: Sorry that I was unclear. Local storage is *private* and, as discussed in the provided link, you can *not* use it to share data. So to "pass" information, store it on the *server* (not local) and have both web sites access it from there.